# Shell, howto extract letters from $line1="Test this... test this!", and print one by one

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am writing a script, which I would like to spice up a bit.

What I need, is a loop, which takes one letter at a time, including space, and then write it on the screen, like an old typewriter would do.

I would write some kind of pause/sleep between the typing, so it would look retro like.

Comment: Isn't using the commandline retro enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind not using pure shell script (i.e., you can mix awk or perl), here it is an example using awk:

```
echo "This is... test this" |awk '{
  for (i=1; i <= length($0); i++) {
    printf substr($0,i,1);
    system("sleep 0.1");
  }
  print "";
}'
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks... working as expected!

Comment: But i would like to use a string e.g text="testsssttt !!"

Comment: This works okay !

Comment: #!/bin/sh

text1="tessssstttttt................... !!!!"

echo $text1 |awk '{
for (i=1; i<= length($0); i++) {
printf substr($0,i,1);
system("sleep 0.1")
}
print "";
}'

Comment: @JesperLykke If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Answer (score 0):

There is some GNU utilites (for example `pv` can do the task `echo "$line1" | pv -qL 10`) but if you'd like can do it in shell

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ -n "$1" ]]
do
 sleep ${2:-"0.2"}
 printf "%c" "$1"
 temp=${1#?}
 set -- "$temp" "$2"
done
echo
```

USAGE: `script.name 'text in single quotes' [interval time in seconds][1]` If you'd like to use variable do the same:

```
line1='Test this… test this!'
script.name "$line1" 0.3
```

[1]: `interval time in seconds` is optional and decimal fraction is allowed